# Laravel FormRequest return custom data on fail

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel's FormRequest to handle validation in my application. I want to return custom data along with the validation errors when validation fails. Specifically, I want to return the ID of the resource the FormRequest is applied on.

Here's the code for my after method in my FormRequest:

```
/**
 * Get the "after" validation callables for the request.
 */
public function after(): array
{
    return [
        function (Validator $validator) {
            $validator->errors()->add(
                'id',
                $this->id
            );
        }
    ];
}
```

And here's my rules method:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'technical_name' => ['required', 'max:255', Rule::unique('softwares')->ignore($this->id)],
        'description' => ''
    ];
}
```

In this case, I don't send the ID as part of the request data, so it's not available to include with the error message by default. As a workaround, I am adding it manually in the after method.

My controller only handles data storage if validation passes, so any additional data must be attached in the FormRequest.

Is there a better way to return the ID (or any custom data) along with the validation errors when using FormRequests?

Comment: depends where you are getting the `$id` from and what you want to do with it. It's not clear what you are requesting.

Comment: If my validation fails, I want to return to the page where the form is present, there to be an id key within the errors array, that has the id of the resource that is to be updated.

Comment: you need to use `$this->route('name-of-id-parameter-in-url')`

Comment: @krisgjika it's a post request

Comment: yes, the url should be something like `/resource/{resource}` and to get that value you can do: `$this->route('resource')`

Comment: You are stating you need the id to navigate in your application. But your application will already have the id to perform the request?

Comment: @mrhn No so basically I have a single form on my index page, where I fill the form data dynamically based on what row I click in a table. If I submit something from that form, and I get an error. I obviously want to put the error back in the form. But if I do that, whatever row I click, the form will always have the error message. so I am trying to fix this by having a data-error tag on my row HTML (the one that has the error). I do this by checking if row->id same as error->id. Thats why I need to pass the ID back for when I redraw the index table so I can do the check.

Comment: I still feel like the front end should know which id it clicked instead of being the responsibility on the backend.

Comment: I would just reset the errors on modal open

Comment: @mrhn yes but when you click on submit the edit form, and you go back, how would I remember what it was? Session storage? Cookie storage? I feel like it could be much simpler.

Comment: thought you had a seperated backend with the front end. Then your solution is probably the best approach.

Comment: where did you get the `$this->id` if the id do not exists in request data ? is it as uri param ?